# Multiple routes to the same razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

**Background**

I've got a razor page in my Asp.Net Core 3.1 website called SignupAndApply. It's effectively a copy and paste of the register identity page but:

- With some additional fields
- Allows an optional applyid to be passed as part of the route
- If I pass an applyId as part of the route, I make a couple of label changes to the page and redirect the user somewhere else

I want to create two routes for this page:

```cs
/identity/account/signupandapply/{applyId?} 'when the user is applying and signing up
/identity/account/signup 'when the user is just signing up
```

I've added the following to the top of the page:

```
@page "{applyId?}"
```

And set the applyId as an optional parameter on the OnGetAsync method:

```cs
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null, Guid? applyId = null)
```

**Issue**

The route with the applyId is working but the /identity/account/signup route isn't.

I've tried adding this to my startup:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => options.Conventions
                             .AddPageRoute("/identity/account/signupandapply", "/identity/account/signup")
                             );
```

It works if I go to one of these

```
/identity/account/signupandapply/<fooapplyid>
/identity/account/signupandapply
```

But not this

```
/identity/account/signup
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong for what should be adding a simple alternative route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page(`/identity/account/signupandapply`) is in area `Identity` ,so you need to use `AddAreaPageRoute` instead of `AddAreaPage` :

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{

    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity",
           "/account/signupandapply", "identity/account/signup");

    }); ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It answered my specific question but has lead to me creating a new question. If you have any ideas with my follow on issue, I'd appreciate any guidance.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60265572/cant-get-razor-page-route-to-work-using-anchor-tag-helper