# Can't get razor page route to work using anchor tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Background**

This is a follow on issue to an [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223804/multiple-routes-to-the-same-razor-page/60257348) I asked around asp.net core v3.1 razor page routes.

I added the following to the startup as suggested in the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60257348/6479619) which allowed me to route to the razor page in both ways I wanted:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => 
                 options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/account/signupandapply", "/identity/account/signup")
        );
```

```cs
/identity/account/signup
/identity/account/signupandapply/<fooapplyid>
```

**Issue**

I'm struggling to use the anchor tag helper to respect the path route `/identity/account/signupandapply/<fooapplyid>`. The href shows using the parameter instead `/identity/account/signupandapply?fooapplyid=<fooapplyid>`. This is my anchor tag helper markup:

```html
<a asp-area="identity" asp-page="/account/signupandapply" asp-route-fooapplyid="@Model.FooApplyId">Apply here</a>
```

Currently, I'm manually setting the href but would like to know how to get this working using the tag helper.

```html
<a href="/identity/account/signupandapply/@Model.FooApplyId">Apply here</a>
```

**Note:** The anchor markup is being added to a view outside of the identity area.

**Attempted**

I've tried adding the below which shows the href as I want. I.e `/identity/account/signupandapply/<fooapplyid>`

```cs
.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/account/signupandapply", "/identity/account/signupandapply/{applyid}")
```

But I then get an error when I go to the page, which makes sense

```cs
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: /Account/SignUpAndApply /Account/SignUpAndApply
```

Neither of these work, the href still shows as ?applyid=:

```cs
.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/account/signupandapply?applyid=", "/identity/account/signupandapply/{applyid}")

.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/account/signupandapply/{applyid?}", "/identity/account/signupandapply/{applyid}")
```

**Question**

Is there a further startup route that needs defining or how do I get the anchor tag helper to respect the path route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/account/signupandapply", "/identity/account/signup")
```

To quote [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pageconventioncollectionextensions.addareapageroute?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_PageConventionCollectionExtensions_AddAreaPageRoute_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ApplicationModels_PageConventionCollection_System_String_System_String_System_String_) on this (emphasis mine):

> #### `conventions.AddAreaPageRoute(string areaName, string pageName, string route)`
>
> Adds the specified `route` to the page at the specified `pageName` located in the specified area.
>
> The page can be routed via `route` in addition to the default set of path based routes. **All links generated for this page will use the specified route.**

So this convention effectively tells the routing to use the `/identity/acount/signup` route from now on to generate all links, while accepting incoming routes to hit *both* these routes.

Unfortunately, I don’t think that you can control this any better using the page conventions. Razor pages do not really fit a routing model where you are having different route to reach the same page. After all, Razor pages are *page-centric* instead of route-centric like MVC actions.

So if this is a hard requirement for you, you might want to look at using a controller for this one use-case instead that renders the same view. For what it’s worth, controllers do mix nicely with an application that is otherwise using Razor pages.

Comment: Thanks, I went down the route(!) of razor pages as the registration page was a good starting point for what I wanted the page to do. However, given your clarification and advice, I'm going to change this to use MVC. My gut feeling is, given the current docs, if I leave it with what appears to be a kind of hack, that there's a chance it'll bite me on the behind in a future release.